# getting user input and storing it in hex

Tags: c, network-programming, hex

I want the user to enter a MAC address in the format : `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff` and then I take this in my code as `argv[1]` for example.

Now how do I store this in an array in hex format?

What I need is the array to look like this:

```
char temp[6] = { 0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0xff }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for e.g. `sscanf`?

Comment: You can use sscanf to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a, b, c, d, e, f; 

sscanf(argv[1], "%x:%x:%x:%x", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
```

Use ints to get the values, then you can place them in char array, since they have byte values.

Comment: That worked. I was using sscanf before but was not storing the values as integers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

An array is not stored in hex format; hex formatting only applies to reading and printing. Internally, all numbers are stored in binary.

To read hex digits, you can use [`scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html), and to print hex digits, you can use `printf`. To let `scanf` know that you want it to read hex digits, use the format specifier `%x`. If you want to read into a `char` instead of an `int, use the modifier`hh`. Here's an example of how you could use it for your case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  unsigned char addr[6];
  char dummy;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of arguments\nUsage: %s ADDRESS\n",
            argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  int res = sscanf(argv[1], "%2hhx:%2hhx:%2hhx:%2hhx:%2hhx:%2hhx%c",
                   &addr[0], &addr[1], &addr[2], &addr[3], &addr[4], &addr[5],
                   &dummy);

  if (res == EOF) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Reached end of input without matching\n");
    exit(1);
  } else if (res < 6) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Got fewer hex digits than expected\n");
    exit(1);
  } else if (res > 6) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Got extra characters after input\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Got: %02hhx, %02hhx, %02hhx, %02hhx, %02hhx, %02hhx\n",
         addr[0], addr[1], addr[2], addr[3], addr[4], addr[5]);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that I read in a dummy character after the input, to check for input that contains junk at the end. This may or may not be necessary for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
sscanf(str, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &temp[0], &temp[1], &temp[2], &temp[3], &temp[4], &temp[5]);
```

Comment: This may overrun memory because %x expects an integer.

Comment: In this case the temp must be an int vector